# Transfer data from one workbook to another

Tags: database, vba, copy, transfer

Im currently working on a code that hopefully does this set of things:

1. From the database file, ask me to select and open a source file
2. Go to Source Sheet, and copy all data on column A, B, D, E, and F from the source file
3. Go back to the Database file(Data Sheet) and locate the next empty row on column A, B, D, E, and F.
4. Then paste all data column by column
5. Close the source file and not save

The current code that I have satisfies requirement 1 & 5 only. Here is my current code:

```
Option Explicit


    Sub Copy_data()
    Dim databasewkb As Workbook, sourcewkb As Workbook
    Dim Ret1, Ret2
    Dim srcws As Worksheet ' Variable for source workbook worksheets
    Dim databasews As Worksheet ' Variable for portal workbook worksheets
    Dim srcLR As Long ' last row of the source worksheet
    Set databasewkb = ActiveWorkbook

    '~~> Get the first File
    Ret1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
    , "Please select the source file file")
    If Ret1 = False Then
        ' Tell the user why the code has been terminated
        MsgBox ("Sorry, unable to proceed without a file.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Open the Source file
    Set sourcewkb = Workbooks.Open(Ret1)

    ' Set the source worksheet
    Set srcws = sourcewkb.Sheets("Source Sheet")

    ' Set the first destination worksheet
    Set databasews = databasewkb.Sheets("Data Sheet")

With srcws
    ' Find the last row of data in the Source worksheet
    srcLR = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row   

    'im not sure what to put here



    ' close the source workbook, don't save any changes
    sourcewkb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    ' Clear the objects
    Set srcws = Nothing
    Set sourcewkb = Nothing
    Set databasews = Nothing
    Set databasewkb = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: Column C is not part of the operation?

Comment: Hi A.S.H, actually no. I skipped that intentionally because I only intended to copy those on the given columns.

Comment: Hi. You can try to put the code given in my answer at the missing section of your code. And BTW dont forget the `End With` ;)

Comment: Let me make sure of something. Are those columns completely independent? I mean, the data values that are on the same row in the source sheet, don't they need to stay on the same row in the destination sheet??

Comment: Yes they need to stay on the same row.

Comment: Then my answer below should work. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'im not sure what to put here

```
    srcLR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
    ' Beware here, use ".Rows.Count" instead of "Rows.Count", because
    ' I suspect you are opening an old workbook in compatibility mode

    Dim srcRange as Range, destRange as Range

    Set srcRange = .Range("A1:B" & srcLR)
    Set destRange = databasews.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    srcRange.Copy destRange

    Set srcRange = .Range("D1:F" & srcLR)
    Set destRange = destRange.Offset(0, 3)
    srcRange.Copy destRange

End With
```

Comment: Hi ASH, im having errors with the (.Rows.Count,1) its saying compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference

Comment: Please make sure that you placed it inside the `With` bloc?

Comment: Oh got it, sorry. by the way do you happen to know an alternative way to automate the process. I mean instead of opening a file. My workbook will automatically open the files that I want it to open and get all those data above and do the same thing but do it as the workbook opens. Am i making any sense? hehe sorry

Comment: Question about the code that you gave and I think i missed this in my instructions. Is there a way that doesn't copy the column headers? the first row on each column is for the headers.

Comment: Simply replace `A1:B` with `A2:B` and `D1:F` with `D2:F`. I did not quite understand your other question. Anyway, I suggest that you make it work this way for now, and once done with it, you can ask another question if you don't know how to modify it ;)